# how could I override Navigator.NavigationBar

Tags: react-native, navigationbar

I want to show different `backgroundColor` of `Navigator.NavigationBar` when I render different components, so I try to change css from various flag, but I always get number type from `this.props.style`,

maybe I don't express clearly, provide some code below.

```
class NavigationBar extends Navigator.NavigationBar {
  render() {
    var routes = this.props.navState.routeStack;

    if (routes.length) {
      var route = routes[routes.length - 1];

      console.log(this.props.style);    // output 92 always

      // so below code doesn't work, I can't override css :(
      if(route.flag === 1) {
        Object.assign(this.props.style, {backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
      } else if(route.flag ===2) {
        Object.assign(this.props.style, {backgroundColor: 'blue'});
      }
    }

    return super.render();
  }
}
```

and be used in my example,

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={{
        component: YellowComponent,
        flag: 1,
      }}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      navigationBar={
        <NavigationBar
          routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          style={styles.navBar}
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

could anybody help me?

thanks for your time.